Infinitive clauses taking object complements
As per my understanding,
"

I find {to do this} very difficult" needs extraposition and should be
written as I find it very difficult to do this.


Is the to-infinitive treated the same as a 'that' clause when there is a transitive verb and object complement? i.e. we need an extraposition for a 'that' clause as in the example:


I find it sad that no one knows the answer to my question.


Could you point to any source that says we need extraposition for infinitives? The Oxford Modern English Grammar doesn't say anything about infinitives in transitive complex cases even though they have it for 'that' clauses on page 309 section 11.3.2.2.

Thanks,
A_Mendes

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

To-infinitive clauses and that-clauses in SVOC clause types are treated the same, and extraposition is necessary.

(CoGEL § 18.35) Extraposition of clausal element
When the object is an -ing clause in SVOC and SVOA clause types, it can undergo extraposition; when it is a to-infinitive clause or a that-clause, it must do so:

You must find it exciting working here.
Cf: You must find working here exciting.
       Working here is exciting.
I made it my objective to settle the matter.
Cf: *I made to settle the matter my prime objective.
       To settle the matter was my prime objective.

Contrast: I made settling the matter my prime objective.
                  *I made it my prime objective settling the matter.

CoGEL: A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language, Quirk et al, 1985

Thanks, LPH! That was what I was looking for.

It says in your answer that When the object is an -ing clause in SVOC and SVOA clause types, it CAN undergo extraposition. Then, why is "I made it my prime objective settling the matter " wrong?

@A_Mendes Determining the why of this seems to be no simple matter, and it is a subject of research. I refer you to the following  research paper which might stimulate your interest: "English -ing-clauses and their problems -The structure of grammatical categories - Hendrik De Smet - Research Foundation—Flanders - University of Leuven".

@A_Mendes I find that you trust CoGEL's judgement there very odd to say the least.

@A_Mendes Did you see what I did there?

@Araucaria-Him Not relying on grammatical knowledge, but only on the  sense for the language that habit has ingrained into me, the reading of your sentence leaves me with an uncomfortable impression; I feel that it is correct only when I add "fact" to it: " I find the fact that you trust CoGEL's judgement there very odd to say the least. ". This seems to corresponds to the fact that "[V that adj.]" does not exist for "find" in OALD. The impression is worse when "that" is omitted.

You won't find anything uncommon in OALD. It's a dictionary!

@Araucaria-Him Do you take your  usage to be an instance in a recent trend, therefore acceptable?

@LPH No, long established and perfectly grammatical!

@Araucaria-Him But all the same, it is a  rather uncommon construction, right? It is then possible that it has not been retained by certain grammarians as they found something wanting in it. Does CGEL refer to it? Do you know? // "I find that you trust CoGEL's judgement" is correct, I agree with that; you are allowed to omit "that". The that-clause is the object, so you can say "I find  you trust CoGEL's judgement". The  that-clause is also an object in the initial sentence, but can you say "I find  you trust CoGEL's judgement there very odd to say the least."? I don't think so.

@LPH You're veering from "a recent trend" to "not retained by certain grammarians", and also implying that grammarians can make up o decide what's grammatical and what's not! That's not how it works in any way shape or fashion  - as the authors of CoGEL would tell you in a heartbeat! There are many situtions where it's not ok to omit that from finite clauses, and one can't malke straightforward analogies from one construction to another.

@Araucaria-Him Misreading me: since you tell me that the construction has been established a long time ago I adjust to the new reality,  the reality you reckon with. //  If grammarians can't decide what is grammatical or not what is the point in being a grammarian? There is an uncountable number of questions on this site asking whether one construction or other is grammatical. // "…  evaluations are made by self-appointed authorities who, reflecting varying judgments of acceptability and appropriateness, often disagree. " (CoGEL): your authority against Oxford's.

@LPH They can decide what's grammatical or not in the same way that physicists can decide which planet is closest to the sun. They can authoritatively tell you, under the right cicumstances, what the acual case is. But the actual case does not depend in any way upon the insignificant opinions of grammarians or physicists in either case.

@Araucaria-Him  I am convinced about the 'that' clauses and the need for {the fact}. Not only CoGEL, but also Oxford Grammar has mentioned it. This question was only for the infinitive clauses. Thanks!

@A_Mendes I'll take CamGEL or Bas Aarts over CoGEL which was out of date when it was published 40 years ago. More impotantly, there's the basic fact that well-educated proficient native speakers and published authors use sentences like the one I gave you earlier which is proof positive that they are grammatical. And frankly, I find that you don't accept this utterly bizarre.

@A_Mendes Did you see what I did there?
